# Embedding mayaVI within wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets, mayavi

**UPDATE:** I've placed print commands within the code to isolate the moment of error. The output for the below code is `a b c d`.  I ended up switching to pyqt/pyside using the alternative code provided, but please let me know if I can help in any other way from my current setup in debugging this issue.

```
from numpy import ogrid, sin
from traits.api import HasTraits, Instance
from traitsui.api import View, Item
from mayavi.sources.api import ArraySource
from mayavi.modules.api import IsoSurface
from mayavi.core.ui.api import SceneEditor, MlabSceneModel

class MayaviView(HasTraits):

    scene = Instance(MlabSceneModel, ())

    print "a"

    view = View(Item('scene', editor=SceneEditor(), resizable=True,
                show_label=False),
                resizable=True)

    print "b"

    def __init__(self):

        print "z"

        HasTraits.__init__(self)
        x, y, z = ogrid[-10:10:100j, -10:10:100j, -10:10:100j]
        scalars = sin(x*y*z)/(x*y*z)
        src = ArraySource(scalar_data=scalars)
        self.scene.engine.add_source(src)
        src.add_module(IsoSurface())

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Wx Code
import wx

print "c"

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):

    print "d"

    def __init__(self, parent, id):

        print "e"

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, 'Mayavi in Wx')
        self.mayavi_view = MayaviView()
        self.control = self.mayavi_view.edit_traits(
                        parent=self,
                        kind='subpanel').control
        self.Show(True)

app = wx.PySimpleApp()
frame = MainWindow(None, wx.ID_ANY)
app.MainLoop()
```

---

**Initial Post:**

I'm trying to reproduce the official code on mayaVI's website for embedding in wxWidgets ([Wx embedding example](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/example_wx_embedding.html)).

The first error occurs while using `app = wx.PySimpleApp()`, and I change it to `app = wx.App(False)` via an online suggestion.

After this step, the program runs without command line error, but hangs during the data visualization step (the python visualization window never opens up, but does appear as an icon).

To test that my modules were installed correctly, I used MayaVI's official Qt example ([Qt embedding example](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/example_qt_embedding.html)) - and it worked perfectly.

**Details:** I'm running Pythonw v=2.7.14 within a conda environment, with wxPython v=4.0.1 (osx-cocoa phoenix) and mayaVI v=4.5.0, all via macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.3.

Any advice on this matter would be a huge help - let me know if I can answer anything myself.

Comment: where does it hang? What is the last line of code being executed?

Comment: @Igor I might be using the term 'hang' incorrectly, but the entire script runs without error; it's just that the visualization window never opens up (even upon clicking its icon in the dock)

Comment: I understand that. But my question was - where does it fail? Did you try to insert some kind of a print statement or use a debugger?

Comment: Hi, I use the same library versions as evambivalence, but work on Ubuntu 16.04 . When running the example code (wx_embedding.py), I get a segmentation fault. The code crashes when executing: "from traitsui.api import View, Item" (wxPython4-gtk3) and when executing: "self.control = self.mayavi_view.edit_traits(parent=self, kind='subpanel').control" (wxPython4-gtk2). The problem does not occur with wxPython3.0-gtk2. Some incompatibility issues between wxPython4 and Mayavi?

Comment: As far as I know mayavi is not compatible with wx 4, have you tried wx 3?

Comment: @christianbrodbeck I actually switched to pyqt after encountering this crash, but if you've checked this out on your end and want to post a solution, I can accept it as the answer for this question.