# Prefered 3-d plot library for WxPython

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython, plotly, mayavi

I am building a GUI application using Wxpython which requires 3-d scatter plots. I have tried using the following libraries but with shortcomings:

1. `Matplotlib`: Very slow rendering, panning and zooming [needs workarounds](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/110#issuecomment-122026421).
2. `plot.ly`: I tried creating a `wxpython webview` and loading the `plotly` html from there, but `wxpython webview` does not seem to support `WebGL` which is required for 3d rendering. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55723043/wxpython-cannot-run-webgl-content-on-webview) for details.
3. `mayavi`: I am unable to figure how I can embed `mayavi` into `wxpython` GUI. [This example at mayavi docs](https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/example_wx_embedding.html)
   just open a blank wx frame. Comments at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48628650/embedding-mayavi-within-wxpython#comment85486625_48628650) suggests that mayavi doesn't support `Wxpython 4+`.

   Are there any 'decent' 3d-plotting libraries which support wxpython or is `matplotlib` my only option here?
   [edit after comment]: The plot should be interactive(at least pan and zoom). The plot should preferably be inside a panel in wxpython. The data will be static.

Comment: This is rather an open question as you'll probably have to balance things out in order to have a plotter that fits your needs (does it have to render using wx/wxpython internals? does it have to be interactive? realtime? fixed or changing data? why wx and not Qt-based?). In the meantime, check the [wiki page for scientific plotting](https://wiki.python.org/moin/NumericAndScientific/Plotting) for a thorough list of alternatives.

Comment: @FelipeLema please have a look at edits. About why only wx? 3-d plot is one feature of the application I am building. Moving the application to something else will require considerable amount of work.

Comment: If matplotlib is slow for you and mayavi does not support wxPython 4, I think your best bet would be to go through VTK and hack the sources of wxVTKRenderWindow / wxVTKRenderWindowInteractor to support wxPython 4. I’m not sure how many modifications will be needed to the sources or if VTK already supports wxPython 4, but it shouldn’t be particularly difficult to do.

Comment: I think, the best option and the hardest, is to implement a 3D plotter using PyOpenGL. wxPython and PyOpenGL can work together without any problem. For this, you will need to learn some OpneGL. It can be done, i did it once with simple shapes.

Comment: @AttilaToth Can you point to some tutorials or documentation?